# My taskbar shows up even when minecraft is in full screen

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have been casually playing minecraft, and I recently went from 1.8.9 to 1.11.2. For a couple days, everything was okay just like normal, but when I come on to play today, Minecraft is being weird. It can fullscreen, but it shows the taskbar of my computer. Because I am OCD, it drives me nuts. Any ideas to why this happened/how to fix it?

EDIT:
Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Could you possibly provide a screenshot for a better analysis of the problem?

Comment: Indeed. I posted one.

Comment: What happens if you press the windows key on your keyboard and then click inside the minecraft window? I know on other applications this works for me.

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue in this case is more a Windows issue rather than a Minecraft issue as @[JeffyBoyy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/300288/75799) states.

You stated that it works fine normally which would imply 90% of the time it's fine. I suggest opening the task manager (`Control + Shift + Escape`) going to details if you can and find a process named `explorer.exe`.

**Note:** This process controls various things, so **before you continue** make sure you close out of important folders, file transfers and any important work is saved just to be safe.

Click on the process name and click on end task OR restart since Windows 10. The confirm that you want to do it.

**Windows 10 note:** You're likely done, but if your taskbar and other things don't come back keep reading.

After that you'll notice that the **taskbar and a few other things will disappear** this is intended. (**Note:** You probably will not be able to alt-tab, or other things to read this so read it and remember before you do this.)

After that click on the `File` menu under the Window title, You'll see a few options click `Run new task.` a window will appear and you should type `explorer.exe` and everything should return and the Taskbar should no longer be in the way (assuming this was the issue, which I've had many times).

Comment: Suggestion: You can click RESTART on the windows explorer process in Process Manager, I think its a new feature to Windows 10 since you didnt mention it, but will be good if you can update your answer, it makes the whole thing 1000 times easier :)

Comment: Yeah, when you click the process in Windows 10 it only has Restart now. I forgot about this answer truth be told. Edited it to be updated.

Answer (score 1):

I did a little digging, and it seems it might not be JUST a Minecraft issue. It would seem, after reading some of these posts, that there is a numbers of applications that will let the taskbar appear on top of it.

This is what I found in this one post:

**"Right click on the task bar. Choose Properties, check box for "Hide toolbar"
Whenever you move the mouse to the bottom of the screen the taskbar (toolbar) will re-appear"**

Also, here is a forum thread where a lot of people solved their problem with some different solutions:

http://www.avsforum.com/forum/26-home-theater-computers/1314371-windows-7-taskbar-visible-during-full-screen-videos.html

Answer (score 0):

step 1: open task manager (ctrl+shift+esc or ctrl+alt+delete then click task manager)

step 2: go to more details

step 3:scroll down to windows explorer (should have a file explorer icon)

step 4:right click, then click on restart

see [this](http://blog.drivethelife.com/how-to/fix-windows-10-taskbar-not-hiding-full-screen.html) post

Comment: No, do **not** do this. This reboots the computer. It does nothing to solve the problem.

Comment: no it doesn't. it restarts the taskbar and fixes the glitch

Comment: You do know that Explorer is the core Windows application, right? Restarting it is generally not advised.

Comment: but at this point its the actual solution to the problem. After you have closed every other application you do not need, its the best you can do before restarting the whole operating system with the computer...

Answer (score -1):

Try F11. It seems simple, but a random click worked for me.

Comment: Welcome to the site! What does the F11 key do in Minecraft?